# Why does my JSON data get lost when passed as a data attribute from erb to Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, erb

I try to pass some stuff (among which a JSON object) from the Ruby part of my Rails application to a Javascript file, and try to do so using the HTML data attributes.

In the .html.erb file:

```
<div id='myDiv' data-points="<%=raw @points.to_json%>" data-unit-id="<%=@unit_id%>" >
</div>
```

In the .js file:

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");
console.log(map_canvas.getAttribute("data-unit-id"));
console.log(map_canvas.getAttribute("data-points"));
```

Data-unit-id does show up correctly in the console log. However, data-points, which is a JSON object, shows up like only this in the console log:

```
{
```

When I log `<%=raw @points.to_json%>` from the html.erb side, it shows up fine as well - so the piece of ruby code does its job fine -, so somewhere while getting passed as a data attribute it gets lost (and `data-unit-id` does not!).

Does anyone have a clue what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quotes. Your generated markup is syntactically invalid html. Attribute value ends prematurely, `data-points="{"foo": 1}"`. See? You think it's an opening quote for key `foo`, but *actually* it's closing quote for `data-points` value.

To avoid this, either escape double quotes in the value:

```
data-points="{\"foo\": 1}"
```

or use another type of quotes to surround the value

```
data-points='{"foo": 1}'
```